# open exported excel file and try to save it, is saving as web page format

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

When I  exported an Excel file through asp.net / C# code, it's saving as a web page:
It's exporting, but when I open the same excel file and try to save it, it is saving as a web page format, how can I change that?
these are the functions I am using for exporting to excel:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report1.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
int bytesRead = BUFFER_SIZE;
byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
///
memoryStream.Position = 0;
do
{
    bytesRead = memoryStream.Read(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytesBuffer);
    memoryStream.Flush();
} while (bytesRead > 0);
///
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to delete your aspx code (see below) into your webpage and leave just this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.Default" %>
```

Part to delete below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

... and in your code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report1.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

            const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
            int bytesRead = BUFFER_SIZE;
            byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
            ///
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = memoryStream.Read(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytesBuffer);
                memoryStream.Flush();
            } while (bytesRead > 0);
        }
    }
}
```